# Getting error while saving python file: There is no Pip installer available in the selected environment

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code

I'm getting an error "There is no Pip installer available in the selected environment." when saving python files in Visual Studio Code. I have pip3 installed, and it's available from the terminal. I have selected the python interpreter in the VS Code. I also tried manually installing autopep8 with pip3 in the project directory. But the error still occurs. Unfortunately, these are the only solutions I was able to find on the internet, but none of them worked. I use Lenovo's Chromebook, which is Debian-based. Does anyone have any clue how to solve the issue?
[image: Message when saving]

[image: The Error]

Selected interpreter:
[image: Selected Python interpreter]

Comment: Does `pip` work in VS code's internal terminal? Does the shell prompt display a venv name?

Comment: pip3 does work in VS Code's internal terminal. How do i check the venv name? I'm sorry, i'm fairly new to python.

Comment: It should be displayed in parentheses right before the current directory as first part of the prompt. Can you extend your question with your selected python interpreter?

Comment: If I get it right, then no, it doesn't: https://ibb.co/GvQtGM9

Added the screenshot of the selected interpreter.

Comment: Then does `/usr/local/bin/pip3` exist? What's the output of `which pip3` in the terminal?

Comment: /usr/bin/pip3. Now I see why the error occurs. pip3 is installed for the older python version. When I change the interpreter to python 3.7.3 everything works. So thank you. But is there a way, to make the new python version work properly? And can you add your answer, so I can mark it as a solution?

Comment: Glad you could solve it using my hints. I have posted a full answer, also containing hints about how to get the other installation working. However, I would strongly encourage you to use a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) instead of relying on system packages, which could change on every package update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously have installed multiple Python environments on your system. The one in `/usr/bin` is usually the one installed by your system's package manager (`apt` on Debian) and most probably the default one that is used if you just call the python commands without absolute path from your shell. You can verify that by calling:

```
which python3
which pip3
```

I assume that both binaries are used from `/usr/bin/`.

Your Python installation selected in VS code is located in `/usr/local/bin`, which probably has been installed from a different origin (maybe you have compiled Python from source?). If VS code complains that no `pip` has been found in your selected environment, probably `/usr/local/bin/pip3` does not exist for some reason. You can verify that by calling:

```
ls /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

Easiest solution to this would be to select the `/usr/bin/python3` environment in VS code.

If you really need the Python version from `/usr/local/bin`, find out where this installation came from and complete it in order to have `pip3` there as well.

The most sustainable solution, however, would be to use a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). This would make your Python version system-independent and you have full control over the packages in there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check in your terminal "pip3 freeze" command, if it shows some list , then pip is working, otherwise you should check the environment variable in your system for pip3.

Comment: Yes, it shows a long list of dependencies of some kind.

Comment: It means your IDE is not identifying the pip3 executable file, I think you can set an Environment variable in your system for pip3 executable and then set it into your IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any idea how can I do that?))

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea of Visual studio code editor IDE, 
but you can set environment variable in your system using this link -> 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session